# Positive-Only Training Classification in Spark ML in Scala

Tags: machine-learning, classification, spark-mllib

I've been reading the Spark ML documentation, but I can't seem to find any insights into how best to deal with training data that only has positives. In my use-case, I'm attempting to use a list of donors as my training set in order to determine likelihood that another list of people will donate. From all the examples I've found, training needs both positive and negative training in order effectively classify results. Is there an ideal way of accomplishing this in Spark machine learning?

Comment: You want to do research on PU learning (PU - positive unlabeled). You can use the standard two-class classified with critical difference what objective is being optimized. In standard two-class classifier packages this is accuracy whereas for PU learning some of popular optimization metrics are AUC (area under the curve) and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SparkML has EM (Expectation Maximization) with Gaussian Mixture which [can be used for anomaly detection](https://codefying.com/2016/09/03/gaussian-mixture-model-with-application-to-anomaly-detection/).

Apart from that, if you run on Spark, you could try H2O, just googling returns a bunch of results on anomaly detection using H2O. For example in H2O you can train autoencoders - the H2O [Deep Learning documentation booklet](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepLearningBooklet.pdf) illustrates them with such application.